# Fetching data from CloudKit with queries in a loop retrieves wrong data

Tags: ios, recursion, swift3, cloudkit

I have an app that uses `CloudKit` as backend.

I have a `Post` record type that has an `user` as `CKReference` in order to keep track from who's the post creator.

My `post struct` constructor takes a `user` as input so I can "mount" the post to display.

When I'm querying the server to retrieve 10 posts I use the following code:

```
var postRecords = [CKRecord]()
var userRecords = [User]()
let qop = CKQueryOperation(query: q)
qop.resultsLimit = 10

qop.recordFetchedBlock = {(record: CKRecord) in
    postRecords.append(record)
    let userReference = record["user"] as! CKReference
    self.userCKReferences.append(userReference)
}

qop.queryCompletionBlock = {(cursor, err) in
    if err != nil {
        print("queryCompletionBlock error:", err ?? "")
        return
    }

    let start = Date()

    for reference in self.userCKReferences {

        database.fetch(withRecordID: reference.recordID, completionHandler: { (tmpUserCKR, err) in

            if err != nil {
                print("Error:", err ?? "")
                return
            }


            let tmpUser = User() // custom initializations here
            userRecords.append(tmpUser)

            if userRecords.count == postRecords.count {
                self.assemblePosts(posts: postRecords, users: userRecords, previousCounter: previousPostCounter, firsTime: firstTime)
                let finish = Date()
                let executionTime = finish.timeIntervalSince(start)
                print("Execution time: \(executionTime)")

            }
            })
    }
}
database.add(qop)
```

As you can see, I fetch the `post` then I iterate through the fetched posts `user` `CKReference` in order to get the respective user that created the post and then I construct my post to present in a `UICollectionView` to the user.

With this approach I've encountered a problem.

I made a test with 10 posts, in which the `post1` was created by `user1`, the `post2` created by `user2`, `post3` created by `user1`, `post4` created by `user2` (and so on...)

10 posts created by these two users, one at a time.

When I'm iterating through the `FOR LOOP` to fetch the users, somehow the order obtained isn't the right one, it mixes the user order.

I expect seeing `user1`, `user2`, `user1`, `user2`, etc...

But I'm given `user1`, `user1`, `user2`, `user1` all mixed and in an odd order, if I refresh the given order will be different from the previous one.

Even if I print the `record.recordID` inside the `fetch` operation when it goes wrong it isn't the same as the `reference.recordID` as it should be.

I though that might be happening, since the queries are made asynchronously and input could be wrong (one more iteration before the query finishes) and the `recordID` to fetch would be wrong, BUT for that to happen I wouldn't have the 10 posts fetched I think, but I get them -- the posts are correctly fetched but the users aren't.

In order to make a test , I created a recursive function that only fetches the next user from the server when the previous one was successfully fetched ,  and by that I notice that the users now are fetched properly.

here's my recursive function:

```
var refPosition: Int = 0
var userRecords = [User]()

func recursiveFetch(list: [CKReference], completion: ((Bool) -> Swift.Void)? = nil) {
    if refPosition == list.count {
        // All data fetched 
        completion?(true)
        refPosition = 0
        userRecords =  [User]()
        return
    }

    let database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
    let id = list[refPosition].recordID

    database.fetch(withRecordID: id) { (record, err) in

        if err != nil {
            print("Failed to fetch user with error:", err ?? "")
            return
        }


        let tmpUser = User() // with some initializations

        self.userRecords.append(tmpUser)

        self.refPosition += 1
        self.recursiveFetch(list: list, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

And I call it inside the `queryCompletionBlock` replacing the previous for loop, which goes like this:

```
var postRecords = [CKRecord]()


let qop = CKQueryOperation(query: q)
qop.resultsLimit = 10

qop.recordFetchedBlock = {(record: CKRecord) in
    postRecords.append(record)
    let userReference = record["user"] as! CKReference
    self.userCKReferences.append(userReference)
}

qop.queryCompletionBlock = {(cursor, err) in
    if err != nil {
        print("queryCompletionBlock error:", err ?? "")
        return
    }

    let start = Date()

    self.recursiveFetch(list: self.userCKReferences, completion: { (success) in
        if self.userRecords.count == postRecords.count {
            self.assemblePosts(posts: postRecords, users: self.userRecords)
            let finish = Date()
            let executionTime = finish.timeIntervalSince(start)
            print("Execution time: \(executionTime)")

        }
    })
}
database.add(qop)
```

This way I guarantee that the user for the respective post won't be wrong, but with this I got an huge performance block.

With the regular for loop my function execution time goes like this:

> Execution time: 1.15568399429321

And with the recursive function it goes like this:

> Execution time: 4.56143599748611

As you notice it's almost 4 times more.

Here's my question:

What might be causing the data corruption inside the for loop? and How can I improve performance in the recursive function?

Could this be a bug in `CloudKit`?

Thank you.
Regards.

**EDIT**

After some testing, I've done the following to the `For loop`:

```
    for (i,reference) in self.userCKReferences.enumerated() {
    print("\nindex:", i)
    print("recordID:", reference.recordID)

    database.fetch(withRecordID: reference.recordID, completionHandler: { (tmpUserCKR, err) in

        print("\nindex inside fetch:", i)
        print("recordID inside fetch:", reference.recordID)
        print("fetched recordID:", tmpUserCKR?.recordID)

        if err != nil {
            print("Error in reference loop:", err ?? "")
            return
        }


        let tmpUser = User(/* with custom inits*/)
        userRecords.append(tmpUser)

        if userRecords.count == postRecords.count {
            self.assemblePosts(posts: postRecords, users: userRecords, previousCounter: previousPostCounter, firsTime: firstTime)
            let finish = Date()
            let executionTime = finish.timeIntervalSince(start)
            print("Execution time: \(executionTime)")

        }
    })
}
```

As you can see, I tried to track the index before and within the fetch, and these are the prints:

```
index: 1
recordID: <CKRecordID: 0x6180002382a0; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>

index: 2
recordID: <CKRecordID: 0x6180002383c0; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>

index: 3
recordID: <CKRecordID: 0x618000238200; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>

index: 4
recordID: <CKRecordID: 0x60000003b600; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>

index: 5
recordID: <CKRecordID: 0x600000038420; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>

index: 6
recordID: <CKRecordID: 0x600000036640; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>

index: 7
recordID: <CKRecordID: 0x600000039b60; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>

index: 8
recordID: <CKRecordID: 0x60000003b780; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>

index: 9
recordID: <CKRecordID: 0x60000003b580; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>

index inside fetch: 1
recordID inside fetch: <CKRecordID: 0x6180002382a0; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
fetched recordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x6100000369e0; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)

index inside fetch: 4
recordID inside fetch: <CKRecordID: 0x60000003b600; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
fetched recordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x60000003c640; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)

index inside fetch: 3
recordID inside fetch: <CKRecordID: 0x618000238200; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
fetched recordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x610000035fa0; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)

index inside fetch: 2
recordID inside fetch: <CKRecordID: 0x6180002383c0; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
fetched recordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x610000038f80; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)

index inside fetch: 6
recordID inside fetch: <CKRecordID: 0x600000036640; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
fetched recordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x60000003c640; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)

index inside fetch: 0
recordID inside fetch: <CKRecordID: 0x608000037b20; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
fetched recordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x618000238560; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)

index inside fetch: 7
recordID inside fetch: <CKRecordID: 0x600000039b60; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
fetched recordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x60800003abe0; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)

index inside fetch: 9
recordID inside fetch: <CKRecordID: 0x60000003b580; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
fetched recordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x60000003c780; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)

index inside fetch: 8
recordID inside fetch: <CKRecordID: 0x60000003b780; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
fetched recordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x60000003c7e0; recordName=25221185-4E74-4268-B3E9-3EF3AA435A76, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)

index inside fetch: 5
recordID inside fetch: <CKRecordID: 0x600000038420; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
fetched recordID: Optional(<CKRecordID: 0x610000039680; recordName=5FF7D994-7F0D-4F1F-90A2-BB765EB52E27, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>)
Execution time: 1.74884396791458
```

Before the fetch the index is correct, but since the loop goes way faster than the fetch, the index inside the fetch goes out of order so with this I corrupt my array.

What's the best way to overcome this? should I sort the objects when it's completed? If so what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are getting the user using asynchronous call , that is why the order of the user is not same, request for first user reference may sometime take more time than for user2 so user2 is appended in the array before user1,

Now what you can do about that:

One choice for you is sort the result after the call

to sort the array you can use sortdescriptor

Comment: exactly what I was thinking. I might modify the `userRecords` to be type `[Int: User]` and for the `int` property I will append the current `index` then when it's all completed I'll sort based on the index (0...9) and return an array sorted :D

Comment: @IvanCantarino good , if this answer helped you please accept it